# ServiceStack/ORMLite: How to conditionally include certain columns in LoadSingleById?

Tags: c#, attributes, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

The requirements of this project require that certain values be retrieved/inserted based on a user's permissions level. So let's pretend I have a DB table "Users" and this class represents the class members:

```
public class UsersDbo
{
   [PrimaryKey]
   [AutoIncrement]
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string CreditCard { get; set; }
}
```

I want to call LoadSingleById on Users, but if the calling user is NOT flagged as an admin, I don't want to populate CreditCard.

The reason I'm asking is because I am working with some tables that are enormous, and a significant number of those values are only relevant to admin-type users, and with a ton of calls being made to the DB, I'd like to only be selecting the specific items necessary for that situation.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

You would call `LoadSingleById` when you want to load references and `SingleById` when you do not, so you can conditionally load references with:

```
var user = isAdmin
    ? db.LoadSingleById<User>(userId)
    : db.SingleById<User>(userId);
```